# How to make ls | less colorful?

Tags: bash, pipe, terminal-emulator

Using `ls` or many other commands, we can get colorful results like this:

[image]

But if those results are too long and after we pipe those results to `less`, the color is disappeared.

This is the result of `ls -l | less`:

[image]

1. **Why the color is disappeared.**
2. **How to make the result of `ls | less` colorful?**

Comment: Checkout your bashrc. Its likely got colour added there. An ls alias is likely

Comment: `ls` is aliased to `ls --color=auto` by default. Try `ls -l --color=always | less`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [man page for `ls`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ls):

> Using the `--color` option without the optional WHEN argument is equivalent to using `--color=always`.
>
> With `--color=auto`, color codes are output only if standard output is connected to a terminal (tty).

Note that `always` is the default.

From the [man page for `less`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/less):

> `-r or --raw-control-chars`
>
> Causes "raw" control characters to be displayed.

So overall, you need this:

```
ls -l --color | less -r
```

Comment: from doc: `WHEN  defaults  to  "always"...` so specifying this is useless: `ls --color | less -r` is sufficient.

Comment: @techno: It does indeed.  However, on many Linux distros `ls` is aliased to `ls --color=auto`...

Comment: @OliCharlesworth, `ls --color | less -r` will work, because `--color[=WHEN]` and if WHEN is omitted, it defaults to `always`.

Comment: @FANGYishu, techno: Ah, I see what you're getting at.  I'll update my answer.  Thanks!